# Can't get data from firebase database

Tags: firebase

I have some code like below and every time when I use Postman to test the data in the Firebase database, it turns out nothing.

```
const ref = admin.database.ref('users/' + '55555678');

    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
        ref.off();
        const user = snapshot.val();

        if(user.code !== code || !user.codeValid){
            return res.status(422).send({error: 'Code not found!'});
        }
        ref.update({codeValid: false});
    })
    admin.auth().createCustomToken("55555678")
        .then(token => res.send({ token: token }))
```

This is the database in Firebase
[Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOX4z.png)

Comment: Your code seems to be for the realtime database. But the image is from firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be using `admin.database().ref` not `admin.database.ref`. (The parentheses are crucial.) Second, the data you have in the database is in Cloud Firestore. Your code is retrieving data from the Realtime Database. Third, `ref.on('value' (snapshot) => {})` Needs the parentheses around the `snapshot`. Hope this helps.